# Anonymous access to share asking for credentials

Tags: windows-10

I have a user who has a Windows 10 Workstation that is not on our domain, but it is on Intune.  The main user, an o365 user, cannot access any shares without being asked to authenticate, even if the share that the user is trying to access is an anonymous share.

However if I log into that workstation as a local user I can access the share without being asked for credentials.

I have made this change without success: https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser

The only thing I can think of is that this is an in-tune setting preventing Anonymous authentication,  But I cannot see one.   Can someone help me find the setting that would do this.

Comment: Your user is logged in; but their login is probably "expired" in some way and need to confirm it. "Anonymus" here means a user can access it without being logged in, but doesn't mean a logged in user can access it without confirming their identity.

Comment: Make sure that NTFS permissions for the shared folder are also allow access to this user or Everyone.

Comment: Thanx all for the feedback but what I eventually ended up doing was removing the intune users deleting his profile then adding the user back to the WS and it all works.